# How to get (used/available/total) disk space with boost or poco?

Tags: c++, boost, poco-libraries

How to get (used,available,total) disk/directory space with boost or poco?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[boost::filesystem::space](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#space) seems to be what you want.

It returns a [space_info](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#space_info) object, which is a simple struct containing data (one of it space available to your application, and total free space).

Comment: @iuwei I have no experience with poco, sorry.

Comment: space_info is a struct, not an enum

Comment: @rve argh that's a stupid typo there, not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
Poco::File("path").freeSpace
```

https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.File.html#14634